# Magento folder change

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I tried to rename the Magento installed folder but it not load properly. Before It store in "demo" folder. At that time it was loaded nicely. I renamed the folder name from that time it shows only text while browsing the website. I have already changed the permission of "var" and "media" folder.

How can I make the website visible with templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the base url from backend or from database in core_config_data table
rename it with your renamed folder.

if you change root folder name than this must be updated manually than only all things will work correctly.

Comment: Hi, I have changed in core_config_data table. and renamed the folder name accordingly, But it wont shows the layout it only displays text

Comment: have you change both url

Comment: I changed the folder name from the table but somewhere still redirect me to the old folder. please help me

Comment: see the structure of basic magento and try to put in same directory structure.

Comment: also check you have properly mentioned your themes package name in backend

Comment: Hi please elaborate which file should i changed. I am new in magento. which file should i need to change. where (location) to found that file?

Comment: Hi its done I have delete var folder and create new one it works. thank you

Answer (score 0):

change base url in core_config_data table

and don't forgot to add "/" at the end.
to load site properly with stylesheet

```
for example: localhost/[your_newfolder_name]/

or
http://[websitename]/[yourfolder]/
```